# IE debugger expecting ";" why?

Tags: javascript

The IE debugger tells me it expects a ; at the bold area and I cannot make it happy. What am I missing here!

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
/* ]]> */
var dateObject = new Date();
var greeting = "";
var curTime = "";
var minuteValue = dateObject.getMinutes();
var hourValue = dateObject.getHours();

if (minuteValue) "**&lt;**" 10)
    minute = "0" + minuteValue;
if (hourValue "&lt;" 12) {
    greeting = "Good morning! "
    curTime = hourValue + ":" + minuteValue + " AM";
```

Comment: Whey are you using if (minuteValue) "&lt;" 10)
It should be if (minuteValue) < 10) right?

Comment: can't see your bold area and there's a "&lt;" in your if statement

Comment: It's not showing up bold but it is the &lt in the minute value where it wants the ";" yet it's already there.

Comment: Put all code to check I have not seen 20th Line

Comment: the line in reference is the if (minuteValue "&lt;" 10) - it is expecting another ; right next to the one that is already there.

Answer (score 3):

check this line `if (minuteValue) "&lt;" 10)`; is the round bracket necessary or it is by mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Missing a ; in last second line  it should be

```
 greeting = "Good morning! ";
```

Comment: That would actually get fixed by the [semicolon insertion](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/) of JavaScript, the `if` statement would be responsible for the error.  Though it is not wrong to point this out :)

Comment: @JasonSperske thanks for the link... i didn't know about it until now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (minuteValue) "&lt;" 10)
```

Here is the mistake

Your should write like this

```
if ((minuteValue) "&lt;" 10)
```

or

```
if ((minuteValue) < 10)
```

Also you missing ";" at here.

```
greeting = "Good morning! "
```

**Also, put end curly bracket.**

```
if (hourValue < 12) {
    greeting = "Good morning! ";
    curTime = hourValue + ":" + minuteValue + " AM";
}
```

Comment: When I do that it expects another ) at column 20. If it didn't have to be strict it would be much easier I think!

Answer (score 0):

Both the below lines are wrong

```
if (minuteValue) "&lt;" 10)
if (hourValue "&lt;" 12)
```

They should be

```
 if (minuteValue < 10)
 if (hourValue < 12)
```

Comment: It has to be strict so the < is not allowed. It told me I had to use the "&lt;" instead.

Comment: @user3199950 Can you provide JSFiddle, It can in understanding your issues more